# How to allow access to a directory and don't allow access to a sub-directory in Apache?‏

Tags: apache-httpd, access-control

I have asked this question on [apache mailing-list](http://www.gossamer-threads.com/lists/apache/users/439443) but I didn't get the answer I want.

I want to allow a directory " /var/www/html/ldap" to two users according to IPs (192.168.1.2 192.168.1.7):

```
<Directory /var/www/html/ldap>
      Order allow,deny
      Allow from 192.168.1.2 192.168.1.7
      Satisfy any
      AuthName "LDAP Authentication"
      AuthType Basic

      AuthBasicProvider ldap
      AuthzLDAPauthoritative off
      AuthLDAPURL ldap://192.168.1.3/dc=example,dc=com?uid?sub?(objectClass=*)
      Require valid-user
</Directory>
```

but I don't want to allow a sub directory to 192.168.1.7 (I want it to be allowed only to 192.168.1.2):

I have tried to add:

```
<Directory /var/www/html/ldap/manager>
      Order allow,deny
      Allow from 192.168.1.2
      Satisfy any
      AuthName "LDAP Authentication"
      AuthType Basic

      AuthBasicProvider ldap
      AuthzLDAPauthoritative off
      AuthLDAPURL ldap://192.168.1.3/dc=example,dc=com?uid?sub?(objectClass=*)
      Require valid-user
</Directory>
```

but it seems that 192.168.1.7 can reach to manager directory because it is a part of ldap directory, how can I forbid this?

UPDATE:

as [Raza](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/26989/raza) suggest I have tried to something like that:

for the main directory:

```
 <Directory /var/www/html/ldap>
          Order allow,deny
          Allow from 192.168.1.2 192.168.1.7
          Satisfy any
          AuthName "LDAP Authentication"
          AuthType Basic

          AuthBasicProvider ldap
          AuthzLDAPauthoritative off
          AuthLDAPURL ldap://192.168.1.3/dc=example,dc=com?uid?sub?(objectClass=*)
          Require valid-user
    </Directory>
```

for the sub-directory:

```
 <Directory /var/www/html/ldap/manager>
          Order Deny,Allow
          Deny From All
          Allow From 192.168.1.2
          Satisfy any
          AuthName "LDAP Authentication"
          AuthType Basic

          AuthBasicProvider ldap
          AuthzLDAPauthoritative off
          AuthLDAPURL ldap://192.168.1.3/dc=example,dc=com?uid?sub?(objectClass=*)
          Require valid-user
    </Directory>
```

Note:

I don't want to be asked for authentication(LDAP AUTH) for both 192.168.1.2 and 192.168.1.7 on both directories (main-directory and sub-directory).

Comment: are you using apache 2.2 or 2.4? In case of 2.2 [here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#satisfy) a useful link were the example is similar to your problem, I think the directive order is the point. If you are using 2.4, consider to add RequireAny and Require ip in conjunction Require valid user. Here is useful [page](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/mod/mod_authz_core.html#requiredirectives)

Comment: unfortunately I use 2.2 version, I try to update it to 2.4 but I didn't find a useful tutorial to do this, can you provide me with useful one @Letizia

Comment: [here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/upgrading.html) is useful link on upgrading 2.2 to 2.4. Did you try to put `Require valid-user` before Order Allow Deny as suggested in link above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about using a re-write rule to block the 192.168.1.7 system from reaching the subdirectory?

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond   %{REMOTE_ADDR}   ^192\.168\.1\.7$  [NC]
RewriteCond   %{REQUEST_URI}   ^/ldap/manager/.* [NC]
RewriteRule   ^(.*)$           -                 [R=404,L]
```

Edited from the original answer; this now sends back a 'forbidden' error code.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but How can I direct the user to the error page, and can you provide a source. @Doug O'Neal

Answer (score 3):

You can create `.htaccess` with the following option, file in a directory that you do not want to show the listing.

```
     Order Deny,Allow
     Deny From All
     Allow From 192.168.1.2
```

steps:

```
cd /var/www/html/ldap/manager
vi .htaccess (use your favorite editor)
copy/past the following :
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny From All
    Allow From 192.168.1.2
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, can yo explain it to me ,and how can I deploy it to my problem @Raza

Comment: should I add the option inside the `<Directory /var/www/html/ldap/manager>`

Comment: you are creating a file called `.htaccess` on the subdirectory where you want limit the access

Comment: I have tested what you suggest but it didn't work, the reason is `manager directory it is a part of ldap directory`. @Raza